# Node Does not Response the GetBlocks Request

Tags: full-node

i can receive the `version` message but node does not respond to my `getblocks` request.

this my constructed byte array :

```
Magic = 249,190,180,217
Command = 103,101,116,98,108,111,99,107,115,0,0,0
Length = 69,0,0,0
Checksum = 11,166,179,194
Protocol Version = 127,17,1,0
Hash Number = 1
Hash = 246,46,200,160,107,31,59,39,28,106,42,100,234,54,127,244,57,
  225,56,86,30,165,128,201,134,109,145,0,0,0,0
StopHash = 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0>>

Request = Magic + Command + Length + Checksum + Protocol Version + Hash Number + Hash + StopHash
```

this is the `request` i send and the node and get no response and i don't know why.
i also read bitcoin developer guide and it did not help.

the version message :

```
249,190,180,217 -> magic
118,101,114,115,105,111,110,0,0,0,0,0 -> command
85,0,0,0 -> length
58,51,118,189, -> checksum
127,17,1,0 -> version
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 > options
144,189,33,101,0,0,0 ->timestamp
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 -> src and dest addrs
230,85,204,238,180,118,227,128 -> nonce
0 -> user_agent
0,0,0,0 - height
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the full sequence of messages sent and received before this `getblocks` (including `version` and `verack` in particular).

Comment: should i send them first before this request? @PieterWuille

Comment: Yes, you must respond to the received version with a verack, and you must send a version message yourself. Without that, the connection is not considered fully established.

Comment: i just notice the response is not verack, its again a version  message. does that mean i'm sending it wrong? @PieterWuille

Comment: question updated @PieterWuille

Comment: When you connect to a node, you send them a "version" message first. They will send you their own "version", and will acknowledge your version with a verack. Then you send them a verack acknowledging their version. After that point, the connection is established.

Comment: thanks @PieterWuille that helped alot,